# busqueda base de datos usando JOIN SQL PHP

Tags: php, base-de-datos, join

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
   function listUser($conexion){
//funcion de busqueda
        $consulta = (mysqli_query($conexion, "SELECT *, p.nombre as personaNombre, p.id as idPersona, d.nombre as nombreDepartamento, u.id as idUsuario, u.nombre as nombreUsuario
                                              FROM persona as p
                                              JOIN usuario as u
                                              on p.id = u.id_persona
                                              JOIN departamento as d
                                              on u.id_departamento = d.id
                                              ORDER BY p.nombre ASC")) or die("Error listando Usuarios: ".mysqli_error($conexion));

        return $consulta;
    }


if($_SESSION['ticket_tipo'] == 1) //if que me muestra los resultados segun //el tipo de ticket con que ingreso
            echo "<tr>
                <td>".$resultado['personaNombre']."</td>
                <td>".$resultado['apellido']."</td>
                <td>".$resultado['email']."</td>
                <td>".$resultado['nombreUsuario']."</td>
                <td>".$tipo."</td>
                <td>".$activo."</td>


                <td>".$resultado['sede']."</td> <!-- PENDIENTE DEBE TRAER LA SEDE--> 



                <td>".$resultado['']."</td>    <!-- PENDIENTE DEBE TRAER EL DEPARTAMENTO ASOCIADO A LA SEDE-->


                <td><a title=\"Editar\" href=\"editarUsuario-3-".$resultado['idUsuario']."\"><i class=\"fa fa-pencil\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a></td>
                <td><a title=\"Activar o Desactivar\" href=\"scripts/actDesUsuario-".$resultado['idUsuario']."\">".$actdesc."</a></td>
                <td><a title=\"Resetear\" href=\"scripts/resetUsuario-".$resultado['idUsuario']."\"><i class=\"fa fa-refresh\" aria-hidden=\"true\"></i></a></td>
              </tr>";
```

buenas otra vez amigos, tengo una duda con respecto al join , me estoy trayendo poco a poco los datos de las base de datos que tengo asociadas a mis base de datos pero me esta dando problemas traer el campo sede y departamento de los usuarios creados.

antes creaba un usuario asignandole un departamento por un value set pero me di cuenta que me traera problemas en el futuro porque no puedo filtrar las busquedas.

alguna ayuda en php?

el show create table de las tablas es el siguiente
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

base de datos

```
sede
CREATE TABLE `sede` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nombre` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


departamento
CREATE TABLE `departamento` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `sede_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `nombre` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 `id_usuario_creador` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 `hora_creacion` time NOT NULL,
 `fecha_creacion` date NOT NULL,
 `id_usuario_modificador` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hora_modificacion` time NOT NULL,
 `fecha_modificacion` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 KEY `sede_id` (`sede_id`),
 CONSTRAINT `departamento_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`sede_id`) REFERENCES `sede` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=4 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1


persona
CREATE TABLE `persona` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `nombre` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `apellido` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
 `cedula` char(8) NOT NULL,
 `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `cedula` (`cedula`),
 UNIQUE KEY `email` (`email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8


usuario
CREATE TABLE `usuario` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `id_persona` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `id_departamento` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `nombre` varchar(31) NOT NULL,
 `clave` char(32) NOT NULL,
 `tipo` set('1','2','3','4','5') NOT NULL,
 `plataforma` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `activo` set('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
 `primer_login` set('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
 `id_usuario_creador` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hora_creacion` time NOT NULL,
 `fecha_creacion` date NOT NULL,
 `id_usuario_modificador` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `hora_modificacion` time NOT NULL,
 `fecha_modificacion` date NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `id_persona` (`id_persona`),
 UNIQUE KEY `nombre` (`nombre`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Comment: Agradezco que muestres los SHOW CREATE, pero sería aun más de agradecer que lo pusieses como texto, es engorroso, molesto y tedioso ayudarte con imagenes, pues no podemos copiar el código para hacer pruebas. Gracias

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacer tantos JOIN como necesites

Ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
  p.nombre,
  p.apellido,
  p.email,
  u.id_persona,
  u.nombre as usuario,
  d.nombre as departamento,
  d.id_sede,
  s.nombre as sede
FROM usuario as u
INNER JOIN persona as p ON u.id_persona = p.id
INNER JOIN departamento as d ON u.id_departamento = d.id
INNER JOIN sede as s ON d.id_sede = s.id
ORDER BY p.nombre ASC
```

Nota: Se puede prescindir de la palabra reservada `as`, su uso se mantiene por retrocompativilidad.

Intenta evitar el uso de `*` para seleccionar campos, y si tienes campos con el mismo nombre en diferentes tablas asignales alias para que no exista ambigüedad.

**NOTA:** @JuanOrtiz Fíjate en los show create que pusiste en la última edición, en lugar de tene una columna llamada `id_sede` en la tabla departamentos se llama`sede_id` este es el fallo por el que no te funciona la consulta tal como te puse y por el que te arroja el error `Unknown column 'd.id_sede'`. Los nombres no coinciden.

---

Puedes ver un ejemplo de la consulta aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37cb0a/1/0

Ejemplo básico para probar en bd, ojo al ejecutar en bd en producción contiene sentencias para borrar tablas.

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS persona;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS usuario;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS departamento;
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS sede;

CREATE TABLE persona( id integer,  nombre text, apellido text, email text);
CREATE TABLE usuario( id integer,  id_persona integer, id_departamento integer, nombre text);
CREATE TABLE departamento( id integer, id_sede integer, nombre text);
CREATE TABLE sede( id integer, nombre text);

INSERT INTO persona VALUES (1, 'pepe', 'husla', 'example@mail.com');
INSERT INTO usuario VALUES (1, 1, 1, 'userpepe');
INSERT INTO departamento VALUES (1, 1, 'ventas');
INSERT INTO sede VALUES (1, 'spain');


SELECT 
  p.nombre,
  p.apellido,
  p.email,
  u.id_persona,
  u.nombre as usuario,
  d.nombre as departamento,
  d.id_sede, 
  s.nombre as sede
FROM usuario as u
INNER JOIN persona as p ON u.id_persona = p.id
INNER JOIN departamento as d ON u.id_departamento = d.id
INNER JOIN sede as s ON d.id_sede = s.id
ORDER BY p.nombre ASC;
```

Comment: me da el siguiente codigo de error .
Error listando Usuarios: Unknown column 'd.id_sede' in 'on clause'

tengo mi tabla sede en mi base de datos . por que ese error?

Comment: Añadela al select, te edito la respuesta. Aseguate también de que el campo en la tabla departamento se llame `id_sede` tal cual y no de otra forma o con alguna mayúscula, `d.id_sede` talcual lo vi en la imagen que pudiste es la clave foranea de la tabla sede en la tabla departamento si entendi bien

Comment: nada, no hay manera.
ya lo intente pero sigue mostrando el error .

Comment: @JuanOrtiz Pues algo no coincide con tus tablas, puedes ver una prueba de esa misma consulta funcionando aqui: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/37cb0a/1/0

Comment: pero cual seria el error , tienes correo? 
quizas puedas ayudarme si te muestro lo que estoy haciendo

Comment: @JuanOrtiz Basicamente el error `Unknown column 'd.id_sede' ` te dice que la columna `id_sede` en la tabla a la que le asignaste el alias `d` no existe. Mejor que una imagen de las tablas puedes aportarnos un `SHOW CREATE TABLE nombre_tabla` de cada una de las tablas para que te podamos dar una ayuda mas especifica. Un saludo

Comment: voy a subirla para que la veas en la pregunta en este momento bro

Comment: @JuanOrtiz Fijate en los show create que pusiste, en lugar de tene una columna llamada `id_sede` en la tabla departamentos se llama`sede_id` este es el fallo por el que no te funciona la consulta tal como te puse. Como indique en el comentario a la pregunta, es mejor para a proxima vez que pongas el texto en lugar de las imagenes un saudo.

Comment: de verdad no lo habia visto, debe ser el cansancio  @Xerif (y) voy a arreglarlo y luego vere si anda la consulta.

Comment: @JuanOrtiz Cuentanos si finalmente pudiste resolverlo.

Comment: estoy en eso @Xerif , se me fue el internet y desde ayer no he podido. en breve vuelvo a probar.

Comment: @JuanOrtiz Finalmente pudiste solucionar tu problema?